# SSH stays open remotely?

Tags: command-line, server, ssh, vnc

When connecting to a server, is there a way to keep the SSH console open once disconnected? Or is there a program that does that, and that lets me connect back into where I left?

This situation can happen for instance if I start a simple manual backup using cp *from* *towards* that takes +1h. I may not be able to wait and have to close the connection, but I still want my command to finish and I may even login later and check the result message.

My current method achieving this, is to login to the a desktop installed on server using VNC. Open terminals remain open and I can let them run something, log off, and come back later and just continue where I where I stopped.

Is that possible within the command line so that I am not dependent on the remote desktop?

Comment: Thank you @steeldriver ! I posted the answer already mentioning tmux as my solution. Will have to wait 2 days though to mark it as answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a command line program called `tmux` that can handle multiple terminal windows and is able to work across sessions as well.